# Running Service Worker cause an error responding to the control function (NET HELPMSG 2186)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services, worker

I am developing a .net Service Worker. When I publish it, I can run the Worker and it works normally. But when I going to make it as a Windows Service, it doesn't run and causes error by message:

> The service is not responding to the control function.
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.

I thought it was because of and exception in the program. But I simplified it to a tiny Worker and see the same error.

The commands in the Administrator CMD:

```
sc.exe create "MyWorkerService" binpath="D:\Projects\MyWorker.exe"
net start MyWorkerService
```

.Net version : 6
Windows : 10
[image: CMD]

I want to run the Service (Worker) and I want to make it running until I stop it by myself.